# Combine conditional-assignment and immediate-expansion in a gmake assignment

Tags: gnu-make

Is it possible to combine ?= and := on a single line in gmake?

That is, can I do this on a single line?

```
ifndef FOO
FOO := BAR
endif
```

AFAIK, '?=' doesn't do immediate expansion.

Comment: No there's no way to combine these.

Comment: @MadScientist Disappointing, but expected.